# Reverse geocoding not available for China

Tags: geocoding, here-api, reverse-geocoding

Hey there I am using here.com API for reverse geocoding. However when I try to fetch a location for China based on the latitude and longitde, I get "undefined" for the city.

What is that so?

Does someone know an alternative for reverse geocoding that works good, fast and affordable, instead of here.com ?

Thanks.

Comment: For China, you better use a local service provider like Tencent Maps for example. They have a [Geocoder](https://lbs.qq.com/javascript_v2/doc/geocoder.html) service and an API that is somehow very similar to what Google Maps offers...

Answer (score 0):

Data coverage from a lot of providers in China is spotty at best. Try a few and see what works for you. https://geocode.xyz/CN and https://geocode.earth are two alternatives.

Answer (score -1):

You could give the Open Street Map [Nominatim Webservice](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) a go, this will perform geocoding and reverse geocoding for you, though I would check out the terms of use:

Below is an example in Node.js (you must install request and request-promise-native):

```
const rp = require('request-promise-native');

async function testReverseGeocode(latitude, longitude) {
    const options = {
        url: "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse",
        qs: { 
            lat: latitude,
            lon: longitude,
            format: 'json'
        },
        json: true,
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': "Node.js",
            'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.3'
        }, 
    };
    let result = await rp(options);
    console.log("Result: ", result);
}

testReverseGeocode(31.2304, 121.4737);
```

If you're happy to go with a paid service, the [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start) is very good and is not expensive if you don't perform a lot of requests:

```
const rp = require('request-promise-native');

async function testReverseGeocodeGoogle(latitude, longitude) {
    const options = {
        url: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${latitude},${longitude}`,
        qs: { 
            key: API_KEY
        },
        json: true
    };
    let result = await rp(options);
    console.log("Result: ", result);
}

testReverseGeocodeGoogle(31.2304, 121.4737);
```

Comment: And how do these 2 services perform in China, as this is what OP was asking for?